# overload [] operator to return a variant type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variant

**EDIT: thanks to the answers I was able to solve all the issues with my code. I post here the solution: it might be useful to somebody in the future. In particular, the suggestion of using a proxy class proved very useful! The example doens't consider all the cases but it should be trivial to add another type to the variant!**

I am writing a C++ (C11 - Linux) custom class that sort of behaves like an unordered map *{key, value}*. I would like to overload the *[]* operator so that I can use the class with the same syntax as an unordered map: *object[key]* would return *value*.

The problem is that I need *object[key]* to return a variant type. I can store internally *value* as a string or struct but, when I retrieve it by using *object[key]*, **I need the returned value to be an *int*, *float* or *string* depending on some internal condition determined at runtime**.

This is why I was thinking about using the **boost::variant library** ... but I am opened to any other suggestion. The only restriction is that the *test* class (in the example) have to compiled as a shared library .so and that the code must be C11 compatible (I mean compilable by GNU g++ 4.8.5).

**I wrote a simple example to show what kind of behavior I would like** The example is not meant to mean anything. It is just to illustrate the kind of error that I am getting. The real class that I am writing has a different structure but the usage of bool::variant and operator [] overload is the same.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef boost::variant<int, float> test_t;

class Test
{
  int i ;
  float f;
  void set(int randomint, test_t tmp){
    if ( randomint == 0 ) i = boost::get<int>(tmp);
    else f = boost::get<float>(tmp);
  }
  test_t get(int randomint){
    if ( randomint == 0 ) return i;
    else return f;
  }

  struct IntOrFloat {
    int randomint;
    Test *proxy;
    explicit operator int () const
    { return boost::get<int>(proxy->get(randomint)); }
    void operator= (int tmp)
    { proxy->set(randomint, tmp); }
    explicit operator float () const
    { return boost::get<float>(proxy->get(randomint)); }
    void operator= (float tmp)
    { proxy->set(randomint, tmp); }
  };

public:
  IntOrFloat operator [](int randomint)
  { return IntOrFloat{randomint, this}; }

  const IntOrFloat operator [](int randomint) const
  { return IntOrFloat{randomint, (Test *) this}; }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include "test.cpp"

#define INTEGER 0
#define FLOAT 1

int main (void) {
  Test test;
  int i = 3;
  float f = 3.14;
  test[INTEGER] = i;
  test[FLOAT] = f;
  int x = (int) test[INTEGER];
  float y = (float) test[FLOAT];
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  std::cout << y << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**To compile and run**

```
g++ -fPIC -std=c++11 -shared -rdynamic -o test.so test.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp -Lpath/to/the/test.so -l:test.so
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path/to/the/test.so" ./test
```

Comment: Your `operator[]` returns `test_t&` - a reference to an instance of `test_t`. If you return `i`, a conversion from `int` to `test_t` has to be done. This constructs a temporary of `test_t`. Returning the reference to a temporary is ... shooting in your own foot (ehm, not possible). I believe, that's what the error message tells you. Not sure how to solve it. Probably it will work if you do it like in your other method `test::test_variant()`: declare `operator[]` as `test_t test::operator [](int randomint)`.

Comment: You are right! By removing the & it worked. My bad. In this way, I can use the [] operator to "set". But how should I overload the [] operator to "get" a value? In that case, the reference & is needed, isn't it? By "set" I mean something like: **object[key] = value**

Comment: You will find many examples for `operator[]` which return a reference. This is done because it gives you write access to the addressed element. (Usually, there is a second counter-part with a const-reference to provide `operator[]` for read-only access also - necessary if the object is `const`.) However, returning a reference is only possible if you refer to something with granted storage. In your case, this is not true. That's why I recommended to drop the `&` which results in return a value. (Returning by value, the value outlives the `operator[]`call long enough to process or assign it.)

Comment: About your extended comment: To return a reference, you have to return something which is an LValue and has sufficient life-time. For your `class test`, this would require e.g. a member variable of type `test_t` to which you could return the reference (for write access).

Comment: @Scheff Thank you very much for the clear explanation. In the real class I do have a member variable of type corresponding to test_t with sufficient life-time.

Comment: Please don't replace a question with a solution - now it's not really a question, and the useful answers don't make sense. Instead, you could add your own answer to show how you eventually solved the problem, if it adds details beyond the other answers that might help someone else.

Comment: Understood. Sorry but I am still quite new to StackOverflow. I won't do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, overload resolution does not happen on the return type, so given

```
int foo() { return 0; }
float foo() { return 0.f; }
```

there is no sanctioned way for the compiler to differentiate

```
int x = foo();
float f = foo();
```

. There is a trick using conversion operator overloads:

```
    #include <iostream>

    struct IntOrFloat {
            operator int () const {
                    std::cout << "returning int\n";
                    return 0;
            }

            operator float () const {
                    std::cout << "returning float\n";
                    return 0.f;
            }
    };

    IntOrFloat foo() { return IntOrFloat(); }

    int main () {
            int x = foo();
            float f = foo();
    }
```

You can force more verbosity by making the conversion `explicit`:

```
            explicit operator int () const ...
            explicit operator float () const ...

            int x = static_cast<int>(foo()); 
            int x = float(foo()); // old-style-cast
```

This proxy (or other conversion operator tricks) are as far as you'll to simulate return type overload resolution.

The idea once arised while searching a solution to supporting `<euclidian vector> * <euclidian vector>`-syntax, i.e. an `operator*` which either means *dot product* or *vector product*, depending on the type of the variable the product is assigned to.

In the end, it was not really practical and did not contribute positively to readability. The more verbose forms `dot(vec, vec)` and `cross(vec, vec)` were superior for several reasons, among which:

- principle of least surprise: the computer graphics community is used to the terms "dot" and "cross"
- less cryptic error messages: because this proxy technique is not idiomatic in C++, people are not used to the kind of error messages this temporal indirection yields
- temporal and/or spatial locality: you are essentially returning a closure with code in it, which can be executed many times at many places. this can be doubly bad as it does not (actually, *does*) work well with `auto &` kind of declarations:

  ```
  int main () {
          const auto &f = foo();
          const int g = f;
          const int h = f;
          std::cout << (int)f << "\n";
  }
  ```

  This prints something multiple times, going hand in hand with the least surprise principle. Of course this becomes less severe if your proxy basically just forwards readily available values. But the error messages won't become any better!

Note you can also incorporate template conversion operator overloads and wild metaprogramming. While worth a fun experiment, this is not something I'd love to put into a production code base, for maintenance and readability will even decrease.

What remains? Infinite possibilities; but some of the most feasible:

- Variant datatypes
- Tuple datatypes (look into `std::tuple`, which comes with conversion operators in case of distinct member types)
- Different idioms (e.g. named methods instead of operator method)
- Different algorithms
- Different data structures
- Different design patterns

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. It will take some time to digest it. In the meanwhile, I think that I will stick with different idioms (e.g. named methods instead of operator method).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return i`, what's happening underneath the hood is the creation of a temporary of type `test_t` that encapsulates that `int` value. This works fine in the function `test::test_variant` because the return type is `test_t`. This cannot work in the function `test::operator[]` because the return type is `test_t&`. The language prohibits creating a modifiable (l-value) reference to a temporary.

One way to make this work is to add a data member of type `test_t` to your class, with your test function `operator[]` setting this member and returning it rather than returning a temporary. Your real class will most likely do something different.

Comment: Your diagnostic is spot on. Your “fix” is a **terrible idea** that will blow up in the most horrific fashion. Please don’t suggest this. Return a value to a proxy object with a defined assign operator instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I assumed that the code in the question is test code only, that the real code "sort of behaves like an unordered map". A map (ordered or unordered) can return an l-value reference precisely because the reference refers to a part of a data member. To emulate this behavior, for testing purposes only, he needs some real object to refer to. Or else he needs to make `operator[]` not return a l-value reference.

Comment: @DavidHammen your assumption is right. The real code is quite different from the example. The {key, value} map is of type {string, struct} where the struct is made up by a string (the value) and a char (the value type). In other words {key, value}={string, {string, char}}. So that when object[key] is requested it returns value with in the correct type.

Comment: @LastStarDust If that’s the case, then what’s the question?! The original code wouldn’t have this issue because there’s no temporary, rendering the whole question moot.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I asked the original question because of a silly error in my code. Anyway, the answers provided me with many hints and insight and now I know much more than before. Isn't that the ultimate purpose of asking questions?